# Confused about IAM Roles, Policies, Statements and Actions

Tags: amazon-web-services

The [Cloudformation documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html) describes the following relationships between the parts of an IAM Role specification:

```
Service (Lambda in my case)
  has one or more 
Role/s
  which contain one or more
Policy/ies
  which contain a
Policy Document
  which contains one or more
Statement/s
  which contains one or more
{Effect,[Action],Resource} objects
  which specify one or more
Action/s
```

Suppose I want to give a [Role] permission to do an [Action]. How do I determine where in the above hierarchy the permission should be specified?

In my specific case, I want to add `s3:GetObject` to a role for a Lambda.

Should I

- create a new Role?
- create a new Policy in an existing Role?
- add a new statement to an existing Policy?
- add a new Action to an existing Statement (using `Resource:'*'`) ?

Looking for guidance as to when each of the above would apply...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do any of the following, the only requirement being your policy document for that role must contain the statement

```
s3:GetObject
```